# How can I get the universal ID of each object in PHP?

Tags: php

In java, there is a default function "hashcode" which is used to get the default universal ID  of each object, in python , there is a built-in function id() which I can get the universal ID of each object, is there some similar function or keyword in PHP which I can use ?

Comment: what would you do with it, if it existed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
<?php
 $id = spl_object_hash($object);
 $storage[$id] = $object;
?>
```

Ref [PHP: spl_object_hash() - Manual](http://php.net/spl_object_hash)